# How to create a storage pool of drives (with existing data) without using RAID?

Tags: ubuntu, ssd, zfs

So I currently have an Ubuntu 20.04 machine that I'm running as a Plex Media Server. It has a 32gb SATA SSD used for boot, swap, `/`, and `/home`, as well as a 2TB M2 NVME SSD that I store my media on (mounted at `/media/nvme`). I currently have about 900gb of media already on the NVME, and I'm getting another 2TB SATA SSD as I'm moving out but leaving this server at my parents' place as they have better internet speeds than I will. I'd like for the new SSD and the existing NVME to appear to Ubuntu/Plex/etc. as a single drive so that I don't have to worry about load balancing the disks manually (i.e. manually putting media on the new drive when the old one fills up), and I'd like to be able to just toss in more disks in the future as needed and have Ubuntu think that there's more space

From some initial research it seems that ZFS is the recommended option, but I don't want to setup a RAID array, as in I don't want to waste any space on parity bits, and I don't want striping as if one drive fails I lose all the data. I just want a system where Ubuntu sees `/media` as a bunch of space without caring about the number of drives behind it, and if a drive fails I just lose that data on that drive and not the entire volume. Is this possible? Can I set this up using my existing disk, or will I have to do some shuffling (e.g. create the pool with the new drive, copy data over, reformat the old drive and add it to the pool)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by using a different solution, [mergerfs](https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs). The way mergerfs works is by mounting your drives to their own mount points (e.g. `/mnt/drive1`, `/mnt/drive2`, etc.) and then creating another mount point that is a union of the file systems of the underlying drives (the [mergerfs readme](https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs#how-it-works) explains it better). This fit all the requirements I was looking for:

- Given a set of drives, provide a single mount point/folder that combines all their space
- Doesn't require re-formatting the drives and having to backup data beforehand and copy it back
- If a drive fails, only loses the data on that drive instead of the entire pool

It also (mostly) accounts for the write-amplification issues that Eugen Rieck mentioned in the comments, as you can set a minimum space required for an underlying drive to be considered for a write. I.e. if you know the average size of files that will be written, just set minfreespace > average size (however if you have less than minfreespace available on all your drives you won't be able to write anything, which is an important caveat).

Using mergerfs, I edited my fstab to include the following to implement the drive pool:

```
# nvme media
UUID=986b13e8-da8d-4839-801e-61d17dcf7d26 /drives/nvme    ext4    defaults        0       2
# ssd media
UUID=674f1abd-ea83-4797-823a-055db6b7c223 /drives/ssd     ext4    defaults        0       2
# mergerfs
/drives/*                                 /media          fuse.mergerfs  allow_other,use_ino,cache.files=off,dropcacheonclose=true,category.create=mfs,minfreespace=10G,moveonenospc=true   0       0
```

The most important option there (IMO) is `category.create=mfs`, which picks the drive with the most free space when doing a write operation. This ensures that data is balanced across your drives (so should a drive failure occur you'll only lose 1/Nth of your data, N = number of drives). Also, since mergerfs supports globbing like you see in the config above, adding more space is as simple as hooking up a drive, allocating a partition, and mounting the UUID to `/drives/{some_name_here}`, and mergerfs will automatically pick it up on the next reboot (and then you can use [mergerfs.balance](https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs-tools#mergerfsbalance) to balance the files out to the new drive). Hope this helps anyone else in this situation!

Answer (score 1):

However you set up a bunch of disks as a single file system without redundancy, losing one of them will most likely cost you all your data. ZFS definitly can not withstand loss of a physical drive in a non-redundant pool.

You have the choice between possibilities:

- Combine your space into a single, non-redundant volume: Lose one, lose all
- Combine your space into a redundant volume: Lose one, keep data, sacrifice space
- Do not combine your space but keep different volumes: Lose one, lose some, manually juggle around

Comment: I see, thanks for the succinct roundup of options! I think I'd prefer the first option, even if it meant I'd lose everything, as I have an offsite backup of all the media so it wouldn't be too much of a pain to copy the files over again. Does ZFS have an easy way of creating a non-redundant volume that I can add more drives to at will?

Comment: Also is there no solution that creates a non-redundant array of drives and just keeps files on separate drives? Say like if during a write operation the disk ran out of space, it would just cancel the write and start over on the next drive, so this way if a single drive was lost only the files on that drive are gone. Or is that just not possible?

Comment: Actually I think I found the exact solution I need for my use case, [mergerfs](https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs), I'll try it out and answer this question if it ends up being successful!

Comment: mergefs will dothe trick for the **read** part, but for the **write** part you are back to manual placement (via mergefs config)

Comment: Could you point me to where it says that? (honestly curious as if that's true I'll need a new solution) According to the readme: "Handling of writes to full drives (transparently move file to drive with capacity)" (more info on the `moveonenospc` mount option). It seems to provide the ability to write as if it's a single drive, and just move to the next underlying drive when the first one fills up.

Comment: Assume you have X GB free on drive A and X GB free on Drive B. Now you want to store a X+1 GB file. You can not store it in `mergefs` because it won't fit on a single drive. If you were to manually move a 2GB file from Drive A to Drive B, you suddenly could. So it is manual balancing. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) In addition to that, every new file you create will be created on the primary FS first, and only if it grows, will itbe moved to the secondary drive. THis will give you an absurd write amplification (1/0 or infinity) on drive A

Comment: That's fair, however I think that mergerfs will still handle things automatically for most/general cases. I still need to read through the docs more deeply but at the very least there's an option to set min space required for a write, so if you know the average file size that will go on this fs (let's say 4gb) you could set min space to >4gb (lets say 8 to be safe) and only drives with greater than 8gb space left will be considered for a write, preventing too much write amplification (and if writes keep failing I guess it'd be time to get a new drive/delete some stuff).

Comment: Don't get me wrong - I don't want to doscourage you from `mergefs`, just pointing out, that the silver bullet for such a Situation has at least some ugly stains.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate it! There's definitely caveats to this solution but the risk of data loss is tolerable and the occasional manual rebalancing of files is acceptable as long as most of the time mergerfs figures it out. Once my new drive arrives and I set it up I'll post an answer with my config for anyone else who might be in this niche situation.